# Business intelligence on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, reporting, analytics, business-intelligence

I want to add analytics and reports to my application on Google App Engine. Can you tell me how I can do that on google's "database"? Are there any oss libraries/tools available?

Thank you

Comment: You want to analyze your Google App Engine application's data?

Comment: I want to analyze my data from bigtable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the new [Map Reduce API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) (it doesn't contain reduce yet, but that's what Google calls it anyway).

This makes it easy to map over all the entities of a type in your datastore and count the things you're interested in.

Christopher O'Donnell has [an article about using the Mapper API for analytics](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/mr/mapper.html). He creates time slices (hour, day, month) ahead of time and maps over those to store the data for each time slice.